# Hide first row of date header in timelineview of aspxscheduler

Tags: asp.net, devexpress

I want to customize the scheduler control to fit our needs. Is there any way that I can hide or get rid it?

[image]

Comment: Is this `custom control or asp.net:scheduler`?

Comment: It's a aspxscheduler control with timeline view. Please see this demo: http://demos.devexpress.com/aspxschedulerdemos/ViewTypes/TimelineView.aspx